# Deploying a Qt application on virtual Android device

Tags: android, qt, mingw32

I am trying for several days to simply deploy a qt 5 application to an Android machine. I have done the following:
1. Install  AVD Manager and use a template device(NexusS, 343RAM, 480x800)
2. Start the device with start->run->cmd-> "emulator-arm @NexusS", emulator start without a problem.
3. Qt 5.1 creator->New Project->Qt quick2(built-in types)
->3.1.Select build kit: Android for arm(gcc 4.7, Qt 5.1.1)
4.In project settings says that mingw32-make is not found and I set it to the path that I found in qt(Qt5.1.1_Android_x86\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe)

5.Build the app, it builds ok
6.Run the app.(the NexusS device remained open)

In the application Output I get:

```
 E/libEGL  (  848): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL  (  848): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 W/Qt      (  848): opengl\qopenglshaderprogram.cpp:319 (bool QOpenGLShaderPrivate::compile(QOpenGLShader*)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): failed"
W/Qt      (  848): opengl\qopenglshaderprogram.cpp:319 (bool QOpenGLShaderPrivate::compile(QOpenGLShader*)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): failed
E/libEGL  (  848): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
......
```

And the NexusS emulator enters the application, for ~1 sec displays the name of the application and after that it displays a grey screen and remaines in the grey screen until i exit the app.

Any ideas?

Comment: which opengl/es api does this android have?

Comment: Where do I get this info from?

Comment: do you have glxinfo by any chance?

Comment: No, I mean on the Android device.

Comment: I tried to get "OpenGL Extensions Viewer" but this emulators are so slow that i cannot actually install the app on the amulator to see the OpenGl info. The thing I also tried is to set in AVD->"Emulator Options"->Use host GPU to enable. I don't get the error "called unimplemented OpenGL...", i get other errors(but not in red) like: QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined highp... The emulator shows now only a white screen when I run the application, still no "hello world.." Thank you